# Почему не сохраняется дата из DatePicker Yii2?

Tags: yii2, datepicker

Пытаюсь сохранить дату из формы в которой установлен DatePicker и не получается...
В форме:

```
<?=
  $order_form->field($order_model, 'date_delivery')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'language' => 'ru', 'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yy',
    'options'=>['class'=>' form-control input-sm'],                 
  ])
?>
```

в модели:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
      ...
      [['date_delivery'], 'date','format'=>'dd-MM-yy','timestampAttribute'=>'date_delivery'],
      [['date_delivery'], 'default', 'value' => null],
      ...
    ];
  }
```

в базе date_delivery хранится в формате DATE, при сохранении ошибок валидации не выдается но в баже появляется 0000-00-00. В чем ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: так может в методе `beforeSave` надо конвертировать дату с `dd-MM-yy` в `yyyy-mm-dd`? Потому что в БД `date` имеет именно такой формат

Comment: покажите пожалуйста пример как конвертировать, проверю

Comment: `\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($СТРОКА_ДАТЫ, ФОРМАТ);` , как пример : `\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date_delivery, 'php:Y-m-d'');`

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте в каком формате идут данные в базу, можно в дебаге посмотреть.
Далее проверяете в каком формате хранятся данные в базе, я так понимаю, что 0000-00-00 явный признак того, что это год месяц день или год день месяц (но первый вариант вероятнее)
Далее приведите данные которые отправляет виджет к нужному формату и убедитесь, что в моделе нет дополнительной логики, которая меняет формат. 
Или же наоборот, в моделе, в beforeSave сделайте смену формата.

Так же могу обратить ваше внимание на этот компонент:
demos.krajee.com/datecontrol
Который фактически решает вопрос, различных форматов в базе и на фронте в виджетах.